# XSLT: when test condition for a child node with a certain name

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I write a test condition in XSLT which says "if any of the child nodes of the current node's child has local-name() = 'abc'"?

For example if the current node has a node named `test` inside it and `test` **may** contain a node named `abc`

I tried writing `test="local-name(test/child::*) = 'abc'"` but it obviously didn't work.

Thnx in advance!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`local-name(test/*)` will check the name of only the *first* child element of the (first) `test`, if you want to check them all then you need to use a predicate:

```
<xsl:when test="test/*[local-name() = 'abc']">
```

but the simpler

```
<xsl:when test="test/abc">
```

may be enough if you don't need to cater for the possibility of unknown namespaces.

Comment: if I wan't a condition for the case when the local-name contains 'abc' should i write it as `test/*[contains(local-name(), 'abc')]`